# How to create a paragraph when option changes in a select tag using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am working in a descriptive data visualization using d3.js. I want to create a template and add information based on json data file.

The template reads a json file, considering a profile picture, a description, and a few numbers.

In order to re-use the template, I create a select tag with different options. I have done this kind of method using `circles` and `modals`. However, the `event` was a `click` method and not a `change` method.

I tried to coded this using a previous example I have done.

This is the code I used:

HTML

```
<select id='opts' class='perfiles form-control'></select>
<div id="perfil"></div>
```

JS

Export function

```
const graph_container = (w, h) => {
let content = d3.select('#perfil')
let jsondata = 'assets/profiles.json'

let test = (vals) => {
  return `
    <p>${vals.nombre}</p>
  `
}
```

Read Json data

```
d3.json(jsondata, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err
  }
```

Add options to selector

```
let selector = d3.select('.perfiles')
  .selectAll('option')
  .data(data.features)
  .enter()
  .append('option')
  .property('value', (d) => {
    return d.image_id
  })
  .text((d) => {
    return d.nombre
  })
```

Attempt to create paragraph based on option changes.

```
let change = d3.select('#opts')
  .data(data.features)
  .enter()
  .on('change', '#opts', (d) => {
    content.html(test(d))
  })
```

The `test` variable is the template I want to create.

In other examples I have used JQuery:

```
$('#opts').change(function() {
  // Read and do something
}
```

But I want to know how can I achieve this goal with my example: using `.on('change', (d)` with d3. Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a dropdown menu, you get the value of the selected option using `this.value`, not `d`, which refers to the bound datum.

```
selection.on("change", function(){
    var selected = this.value;
    //selected contains the selected option
})
```

Here is a simple demo:

```js
var data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
var body = d3.select("body");
var div = d3.select("#myDiv")
var sel = body.append("select");
var opts = sel.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("option")
  .attr("value", function(d) {
    return d
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d
  });
  
div.html("The selected option is: " + d3.select("select").node().value)

sel.on("change", function(d) {
  div.html("The selected option is: " + this.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Gerado. I tried your example. Thanks. Since I'm using `.on('change')`, the first option (i,e, _foo_) is not shown in document when I click on it, it works only for different selected option. Is there a trick to show the information related to _foo_?